# What's the meaning of the tilde icon [~] at the Xcode's source control SCM status indication?

Tags: xcode, svn, version-control

I know all meanings of the rest of SCM status in the project navigator by the Xcode4 reference [Managing Versions of Your Project](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/SCM/SCM.html)

But what is this?

[image]

I've got folder and files from co-worker and included it into my project as 'Create folder references for any added folders' like below.

[image]

and it worked well.

But after putting this folder to my project, there came up wave icon [~] on the navigator and I couldn't upload or commit this folder and below files in it. It tells me that

[image]

and nothings go forward.

I searched many sites include apple forum but all the results are only about [M],[U],[A],[D],[I],[R],[-],[?] except for [~]. So I really want to know this and the way I can upload or commit this 'include' folder.

Comment: `~` has a meaning in Subversion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/853405/what-does-the-subversion-status-symbol-mean

Answer (score 0):

I assume it is under Subversion control.
Then look at [svn status](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.status.html) manual for "~".

> Item is versioned as one kind of object (file, directory, link), but
>   has been replaced by a different kind of object.