# How can I remove “~” in .xcodeproj file with svn

Tags: ios, svn, xcode4

I am using svn and Xcode 4. When I do

```
svn status
```

the output is:

```
~       HelloWorld.xcodeproj
```

How can I remove the "~" symbol?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does the Subversion status symbol "~" mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/853405/what-does-the-subversion-status-symbol-mean)

Comment: I tested all proposal in that thread, but I think the special format of xcodeproj does that my attempts didn´t work.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with part of answer of:

[What does the Subversion status symbol "~" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/853405/what-does-the-subversion-status-symbol-mean)

But I had to remove all .svn folders in the xcodeproj  packet and then to do the process:

Best solution is to rename the new object (in your case, the directory); "svn remove" the object from the repository which is causing the collision (probably a file you've deleted), Commit, then rename the new object back and "svn add" it to the repository. Commit again. You'll have a sequence of 3 revisions where the old object existed, was removed, and the new object was added, respectively. –

Brian Lacy D